# Display sum in text and numeric value excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

i am working with excel sheet. i want to add two numbers and want to display result both in number and text. if you add one and two the result will be three. i want to display result in both shape like in text and number together. please help me to solve my problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you search for 'excel cheque writing'.

Comment: thanks for your comment but its not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a more complete reference than the links provided in the answer:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testNumbers()
    MsgBox nrToWord(99)                 '-> "Ninety-Nine"
    MsgBox nrToWord("three")            '-> "3"
    MsgBox wordToNr(21)                 '-> "Twenty-One"
    MsgBox wordToNr("seventy five")     '-> "75"
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Helper functions:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SP     As String = "-"    'SeParator (dash)
Private Const ITM_00 As String = "zero"
Private Const ITM_01 As String = "one"
Private Const ITM_02 As String = "two"
Private Const ITM_03 As String = "three"
Private Const ITM_04 As String = "four"
Private Const ITM_05 As String = "five"
Private Const ITM_06 As String = "six"
Private Const ITM_07 As String = "seven"
Private Const ITM_08 As String = "eight"
Private Const ITM_09 As String = "nine"

Private Const ITM_TEEN As String = "teen"
Private Const ITM_11 As String = "eleven"
Private Const ITM_12 As String = "twelve"
Private Const ITM_13 As String = "thir" & ITM_TEEN
Private Const ITM_14 As String = ITM_04 & ITM_TEEN
Private Const ITM_15 As String = "fif" & ITM_TEEN
Private Const ITM_16 As String = ITM_06 & ITM_TEEN
Private Const ITM_17 As String = ITM_07 & ITM_TEEN
Private Const ITM_18 As String = "eigh" & ITM_TEEN
Private Const ITM_19 As String = "nine" & ITM_TEEN
Private Const ITM_10 As String = "ten"
Private Const ITM_20 As String = "twenty"
Private Const ITM_30 As String = "thirty"
Private Const ITM_40 As String = "forty"
Private Const ITM_50 As String = "fifty"
Private Const ITM_60 As String = "sixty"
Private Const ITM_70 As String = "seventy"
Private Const ITM_80 As String = "eighty"
Private Const ITM_90 As String = "ninety"
Private Const NR1000 As Long = 1000

Private Const LARGE_SET_1_01 As String = "hundred"
Private Const LARGE_SET_1_02 As String = "thousand"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_01 As String = "million"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_02 As String = "billion (milliard)"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_03 As String = "trillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_04 As String = "quadrillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_05 As String = "quintillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_06 As String = "sextillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_07 As String = "septillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_08 As String = "octillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_09 As String = "nonillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_2_10 As String = "decillion"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_01 As String = "1000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_02 As String = "1000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_03 As String = "1000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_04 As String = "1000000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_05 As String = "1000000000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_06 As String = "1000000000000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_07 As String = "1000000000000000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_08 As String = "1000000000000000000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_09 As String = "1000000000000000000000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_NUM_2_10 As String = "1000000000000000000000000000000000"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_01 As String = "undecillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_02 As String = "duodecillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_03 As String = "tredecillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_04 As String = "quattuordecillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_05 As String = "quindecillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_06 As String = "sexdecillion (sedecillion)"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_07 As String = "septendecillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_08 As String = "octodecillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_09 As String = "novemdecillion (novendecillion)"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_10 As String = "vigintillion"
Private Const LARGE_SET_3_11 As String = "centillion"

'Private nrAsWords As Dictionary, wordsAsNr As Dictionary, nr(0 To 100) As Long
Private nrAsWords As Object, wordsAsNr As Object, nr(0 To 100) As Long



Sub testNumbers()
    MsgBox nrToWord(99)                 '-> "Ninety-Nine"
    MsgBox nrToWord("three")            '-> "3"
    MsgBox wordToNr("21")               '-> "Twenty-One"
    MsgBox wordToNr("seventy five")     '-> "75"
End Sub



Public Function nrToWord(ByVal num As String, Optional propr As Boolean =True) As String
    Dim result As String, nr As Variant
    setNumberAndWordLists
    nr = Val(num)
    If IsNumeric(nr) And Val(nr) > 0 Then
        result = nrAsWords(nr)
        If propr Then
            result = Replace(StrConv(Replace(result, SP, " "), vbProperCase), " ", SP)
        End If
    Else
        result = wordsAsNr(Replace(num, " ", SP))
    End If
    nrToWord = result
End Function

Public Function wordToNr(ByVal txt As String) As String
    wordToNr = nrToWord(txt)
End Function



Private Sub setNumberAndWordLists()
    If nrAsWords Is Nothing Then
        Dim i As Byte
        For i = 0 To 100
            nr(i) = i
        Next
        Set nrAsWords = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
        Set wordsAsNr = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
        nrAsWords.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare    'case sensitive
        wordsAsNr.CompareMode = vbTextCompare      'case insensitive
        With nrAsWords
            .Add Key:=nr(0), Item:=ITM_00
            .Add Key:=nr(1), Item:=ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(2), Item:=ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(3), Item:=ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(4), Item:=ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(5), Item:=ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(6), Item:=ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(7), Item:=ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(8), Item:=ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(9), Item:=ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(10), Item:=ITM_10
            .Add Key:=nr(11), Item:=ITM_11
            .Add Key:=nr(12), Item:=ITM_12
            .Add Key:=nr(13), Item:=ITM_13
            .Add Key:=nr(14), Item:=ITM_14
            .Add Key:=nr(15), Item:=ITM_15
            .Add Key:=nr(16), Item:=ITM_16
            .Add Key:=nr(17), Item:=ITM_17
            .Add Key:=nr(18), Item:=ITM_18
            .Add Key:=nr(19), Item:=ITM_19
            .Add Key:=nr(20), Item:=ITM_20
            .Add Key:=nr(21), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(22), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(23), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(24), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(25), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(26), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(27), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(28), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(29), Item:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(30), Item:=ITM_30
            .Add Key:=nr(31), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(32), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(33), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(34), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(35), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(36), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(37), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(38), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(39), Item:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(40), Item:=ITM_40
            .Add Key:=nr(41), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(42), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(43), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(44), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(45), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(46), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(47), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(48), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(49), Item:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(50), Item:=ITM_50
            .Add Key:=nr(51), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(52), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(53), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(54), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(55), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(56), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(57), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(58), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(59), Item:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(60), Item:=ITM_60
            .Add Key:=nr(61), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(62), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(63), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(64), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(65), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(66), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(67), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(68), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(69), Item:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(70), Item:=ITM_70
            .Add Key:=nr(71), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(72), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(73), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(74), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(75), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(76), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(77), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(78), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(79), Item:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(80), Item:=ITM_80
            .Add Key:=nr(81), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(82), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(83), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(84), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(85), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(86), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(87), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(88), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(89), Item:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(90), Item:=ITM_90
            .Add Key:=nr(91), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_01
            .Add Key:=nr(92), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_02
            .Add Key:=nr(93), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_03
            .Add Key:=nr(94), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_04
            .Add Key:=nr(95), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_05
            .Add Key:=nr(96), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_06
            .Add Key:=nr(97), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_07
            .Add Key:=nr(98), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_08
            .Add Key:=nr(99), Item:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_09
            .Add Key:=nr(100), Item:=LARGE_SET_1_01
            .Add Key:=NR1000, Item:=LARGE_SET_1_02
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_01, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_01  '1 & String(6, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_02, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_02  '1 & String(9, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_03, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_03  '1 & String(12, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_04, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_04  '1 & String(15, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_05, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_05  '1 & String(18, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_06, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_06  '1 & String(21, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_07, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_07  '1 & String(24, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_08, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_08  '1 & String(27, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_09, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_09  '1 & String(30, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_NUM_2_10, Item:=LARGE_SET_2_10  '1 & String(33, 0)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_01, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_01
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_02, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_02
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_03, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_03
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_04, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_04
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_05, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_05
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_06, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_06
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_07, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_07
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_08, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_08
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_09, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_09
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_10, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_10
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_11, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_11
        End With
        With wordsAsNr
            .Add Key:=ITM_00, Item:=nr(0)
            .Add Key:=ITM_01, Item:=nr(1)
            .Add Key:=ITM_02, Item:=nr(2)
            .Add Key:=ITM_03, Item:=nr(3)
            .Add Key:=ITM_04, Item:=nr(4)
            .Add Key:=ITM_05, Item:=nr(5)
            .Add Key:=ITM_06, Item:=nr(6)
            .Add Key:=ITM_07, Item:=nr(7)
            .Add Key:=ITM_08, Item:=nr(8)
            .Add Key:=ITM_09, Item:=nr(9)
            .Add Key:=ITM_10, Item:=nr(10)
            .Add Key:=ITM_11, Item:=nr(11)
            .Add Key:=ITM_12, Item:=nr(12)
            .Add Key:=ITM_13, Item:=nr(13)
            .Add Key:=ITM_14, Item:=nr(14)
            .Add Key:=ITM_15, Item:=nr(15)
            .Add Key:=ITM_16, Item:=nr(16)
            .Add Key:=ITM_17, Item:=nr(17)
            .Add Key:=ITM_18, Item:=nr(18)
            .Add Key:=ITM_19, Item:=nr(19)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20, Item:=nr(20)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(21)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(22)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(23)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(24)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(25)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(26)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(27)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(28)
            .Add Key:=ITM_20 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(29)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30, Item:=nr(30)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(31)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(32)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(33)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(34)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(35)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(36)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(37)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(38)
            .Add Key:=ITM_30 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(39)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40, Item:=nr(40)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(41)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(42)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(43)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(44)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(45)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(46)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(47)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(48)
            .Add Key:=ITM_40 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(49)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50, Item:=nr(50)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(51)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(52)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(53)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(54)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(55)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(56)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(57)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(58)
            .Add Key:=ITM_50 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(59)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60, Item:=nr(60)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(61)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(62)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(63)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(64)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(65)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(66)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(67)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(68)
            .Add Key:=ITM_60 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(69)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70, Item:=nr(70)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(71)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(72)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(73)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(74)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(75)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(76)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(77)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(78)
            .Add Key:=ITM_70 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(79)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80, Item:=nr(80)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(81)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(82)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(83)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(84)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(85)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(86)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(87)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(88)
            .Add Key:=ITM_80 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(89)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90, Item:=nr(90)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_01, Item:=nr(91)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_02, Item:=nr(92)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_03, Item:=nr(93)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_04, Item:=nr(94)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_05, Item:=nr(95)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_06, Item:=nr(96)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_07, Item:=nr(97)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_08, Item:=nr(98)
            .Add Key:=ITM_90 & SP & ITM_09, Item:=nr(99)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_1_01, Item:=nr(100)
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_1_02, Item:=NR1000
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_01, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_01  '1,000,000
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_02, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_02  '1,000,000,000
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_03, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_03  '1,000,000,000,000
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_04, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_04  '1,000,000,000,000,000
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_05, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_05  '1,000,000,000,000,000,000
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_06, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_06
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_07, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_07
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_08, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_08
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_09, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_09
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_2_10, Item:=LARGE_NUM_2_10
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_01, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_01
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_02, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_02
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_03, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_03
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_04, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_04
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_05, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_05
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_06, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_06
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_07, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_07
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_08, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_08
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_09, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_09
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_10, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_10
            .Add Key:=LARGE_SET_3_11, Item:=LARGE_SET_3_11
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: thanks very much this works for me  thanks again for your time.